# how to attach a body to a rope and making it swing to another rope

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, 2d, box2d-iphone

I've set some ropes (using cocos2d and box2d) and would like to attach a body to one rope in such a way that it can swing to another rope. I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Way too broad a question... start by learning physics? And does the world need another cut-the-rope clone game?

Comment: I understand box2d physics and I am not trying to make a cut-the-rope clone. I've set the ropes in place. I just need some guidelines. Eg, the types of joints to use and some other important stuff to consider.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check this [Verlet Rope](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1112) ?